# Creating two objects in Rails 4 controller with strong_params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

In my Rails 4 Controller action, I'm passing the following params:

```
{"user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "profile"=>{"birthday"=>nil, "gender"=>nil, "location"=>"", "name"=>""}}}
```

Now from those params I'm hoping to create two objects: `User` and its `Profile`.

I've tried iterations of the following code but can't get passed `strong_params` issues:

```
def create
  user = User.new(user_params)
  profile = user.build_profile(profile_params)

  ...
end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
    end

    def profile_params
      params[:user].require(:profile).permit(:name, :birthday, :gender, :location)
    end
```

Since the code above throws an `Unpermitted parameters: profile` error, I'm wondering if the `profile_params` method is even ever getting hit. It almost feels like I need to require `profile` in `user_params` and handle that. I've tried that as well, changing my `strong_params` methods to:

```
def create
  user = User.new(user_params)
  profile_params = user_params.delete(:profile)
  profile = user.build_profile(profile_params)

  ...
end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, profile: [:name, :birthday, :gender, :location])
  end
```

But I get `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch - Profile(#70250830079180) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#70250792292140):`

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
user = User.new(user_params.except(:profile))
profile = user.build_profile(user_params[:profile])
```

You could also use [Rails' nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). In that case, the profile params would be nested within the key `:profile_attributes`.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about except. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is without a doubt a time when nested parameters should be used.

You should make the following changes:

model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :profiles,  :allow_destroy => true 
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Users controller:

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, profile_attributes: [:name, :birthday, :gender, :location])
end  #you might need to make it profiles_attributes (plural)
```

In your form view, make sure to use the fields_for method for your profiles attributes.

Comment: Definitely valid about using nested attributes. Thanks for the reminder there.